# Conditionally removing add-to-cart button and hiding prices for product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

In WooCommerce, I am trying to remove Add-to-cart button from my homepage slider based on certain product categories and hiding the prices.

I have tried to use that code:

```
/* Code for authorisation */

function show_price_logged($price){
if(! is_user_logged_in()) {

        if(has_term( 'teamine', 'product_cat' )){  /* sub categories need not authorisation, but thier parent category needs authorisation */
            return $price;
        }
        if(has_term( 'epicuren', 'product_cat' ) || has_term( 'revision', 'product_cat' ) || has_term( 'image-2', 'product_cat' )){  /* categories needs authorisation */
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );    
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
            return '<a class="amount authorizelink" href="/how-to-get-authorized-its-easy">Authorization needed to purchase <span>Click Here</span></a>';
    }
        if(has_term( 'skinceuticals', 'product_cat' ) || has_term( 'lira', 'product_cat' )){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );    
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
            return '<a href="www.radiantskincarespa.com">Please contact the Spa to arrange a consultation and to purchase this product <span></span></a>';
    }
    else{
        return $price;
    }
}
else return $price;
}
```

But it's not working as expected and add-to-cart buttons are not removed when conditions are matched.

Any help will be appreciated. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

UPDATED

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Where are you calling or hooking your function `show_price_logged($price)` ?

Answer (score 4):

As you don't provide any hook for your function usage, to test it and make it work I have used here `woocommerce_price_html` and `woocommerce_sale_price_html` filters hooks (for simple products).

I have changed a little bit your code and it is working successfully now:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_price_html','show_price_logged', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_price_html','show_price_logged', 10, 2 );

function show_price_logged( $price, $product ){

    if( !is_user_logged_in() && !has_term( 'teamine', 'product_cat', $product->id ) ){

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );

        if( has_term( 'epicuren', 'product_cat', $product->id ) || has_term( 'revision', 'product_cat', $product->id ) || has_term( 'image-2', 'product_cat', $product->id ) )
        {
            $price = '<a class="amount authorizelink" href="/how-to-get-authorized-its-easy">Authorization needed to purchase <span>Click Here</span></a>';
        }
        elseif( has_term( 'skinceuticals', 'product_cat', $product->id ) || has_term( 'lira', 'product_cat', $product->id ) )
        {
            $price = '<a href="www.radiantskincarespa.com">Please contact the Spa to arrange a consultation and to purchase this product <span></span></a>';
        }
        else // set here another text + link in case of…
        {
            $price = '<a href="#">LINK </a><span>NON LOGGED USER / NO TARGETED CATEGORY</span>';
        }
    }

    return $price;
}
```

> I have add a final condition (in case of) that will need a custom text + link…

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works, it should also work for you.

---

**Update:** See the result here on a test server:

SHOP PAGE (OR ARCHIVES):

[image: PRODUCTS ON SHOP PAGE]

PRODUCT PAGES:

[image: PRODUCT PAGES]

This just works perfectly…

> **Related to your error in the comments:
>
>   `Warning: Missing argument 2 for show_price_logged() …`**:
>
> This means that you have forget the **`$product`** argument in four function. you need to have this:
>
> ```
> function show_price_logged( $price, $product ){
> ```
>
> Instead of this:
>
> ```
> function show_price_logged( $price ){
> ```
>
> **As you are declaring 2 arguments at the end of your `add_filter()` hooks…**

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 2 for show_price_logged() in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas16_data03/22/3703422/html/wp-content/themes/flatastic-child/functions.php

Comment: @user3696585 I have updated my answer with an explanation at the end related to your error. I have also changed the **`||`** for a **`&&`** instead in the first `if` statement. **This code works perfectly, I have retested it.**

Comment: I am Updating question with screenshot of the Product Slider

Comment: @user3696585 Sorry but this code is perfectly working, I retest-it just now… I have updated my answer with a new  screenshot of the shop page. This problem is certainly relate do your theme, and to be sure, first make a backup of database, switch to a Wordpress default theme, add the code to the function.php file of this default theme and save. You will see that the code is just working.